# How do you upload pictures with MaxiGallery?

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

It seems like everyone has found this without trouble.

I do not see an upload button anywhere.

Any pics / explanation greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example of ModX and it's plugins to be awfully designed both programmatically, and in GUI as well.

On the resource your are editing, click on `preview`.

You will see a `manage images` button.

Click that, and the form will appear for uploading images.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MODX Evolution I would recommend using EvoGallery instead of MaxiGallery. It is all backend and you can upload multiple files in one go.